# Is there a way to suppress single quotes in YamlScalarNode output?

Tags: yamldotnet

Consider this simple program:

```
using System;
using YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel;

namespace TestYamlNode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var scalarNode = new YamlScalarNode("!yada");
            scalarNode.Style = YamlDotNet.Core.ScalarStyle.Plain;
            var serializer = new YamlDotNet.Serialization.Serializer();
            serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, scalarNode);

            scalarNode = new YamlScalarNode("yada");
            scalarNode.Style = YamlDotNet.Core.ScalarStyle.Plain;
            serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, scalarNode);
        }
    }
}
```

The oputput of the program is:

'!yada'

yada

Is there a way to tell YamlDotNet to not include single quotes in the output when it has characters like !, { etc. included in it?
For some context, I'm processing a AWS SAM template that has a property that looks like this:

uri: !Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${PetStorePetFunc.Arn}/invocations

Answer (score 0):

OK - so after playing with this a bit, I realized that I asked what might be a dumb question.
In my use case I'm trying to generate an output with the form:

```
uri: !Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${PetStorePetFunc.Arn}/invocations
```

It looks like the correct way to do this is to use the Tag property on the YamlScalarNode:
example:

```
var node = new YamlScalarNode("arn:${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${PetStorePetFunc.Arn}/invocations");
node.Tag = "!Sub";
```